# Python recursive function to remove None

Tags: python, recursion

The output of this function will also append "None" to the list. Is there a way of avoiding that?

```
out = []
n = 3
def helper(cur):
    if len(cur) == n:
        return cur

    for nei in ['a', 'b', 'c']:
        if not cur or nei != cur[-1]:
            out.append(helper(cur+nei))

helper('')
```

Basically any string with length of 'n', of which any two adjacent letters are different will be output.
I tried to get the output like this but without "None".

```
['aba',
 'abc',
 None,
 'aca',
 'acb',
 None,
 None,
 'bab',
 'bac',
 None,
 'bca',
 'bcb',
 None,
 None,
 'cab',
 'cac',
 None,
 'cba',
 'cbc',
 None,
 None]
```

Comment: could you tell us what you are trying to accomplish, and your expected output?

Comment: `helper` returns `None` *unless* `len(cur) == n`. What is it supposed to return otherwise?

Comment: Simply test for it before you append.  Where are you stuck with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to test the result of `helper`, just append to `out` at end of recursion

```
def helper(cur, out, n):
    if len(cur) == n:
        out.append(cur)
        return

    for nei in ['a', 'b', 'c']:
        if not cur or nei != cur[-1]:
            helper(cur+nei, out, n)

out = []
helper('', out, 3)
print(out)
```

Answer (score 3):

Check the return value from the recursive call, and don't append it if it's empty.

It's also a bad idea to use global variables. `out` and `n` should be parameters.

```
def helper(cur, out, n):
    if len(cur) == n:
        return cur

    for nei in ['a', 'b', 'c']:
        if not cur or nei != cur[-1]:
            result = helper(cur+nei, out, n)
            if result:
                out.append(result)

out = []
helper('', out, 3)
print(out)
```